# Need help to identify this circa WW1, American uniform

Tags: united-states, military, identification

My great grandfather disappeared in 1930 and the only record I have of him is these photos. He fathered my grandmother in 1914 in Australia and had a second family in the late 1920's. I have only just discovered his second family via ancestry DNA testing. His grand daughter provided me with the photos. I can tell that he's a musician but I don't know what branch of the services he was in. I can only assume that it's a US uniform as it appears to resemble a First World War uniform.[image]

Comment: Based on the lyre arm band and `US` on the collar, he was a bandsman in the Regular Army..

Comment: Any idea of what period this might be? Particularly if it's pre or post 1930?

Comment: If I read the collar device right, between 1910 and 1937. After 1937 it became `U.S.`, I believe.

Comment: what are the wraps called that are on the soldiers legs

Comment: @peggymiller See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puttee

Answer (score 4):

There's not much that can be said that hasn't already.

That's the uniform of a enlisted United States Army "doughboy". The uniform dates from between the first and second world wars.

[image: Doughboy 1918]

The insignia is that of the [US Army Band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_branch_insignia#Branch_of_service_insignia).

[image: US Army Band Leader Insignia 1930s]

Note: The above insignia is "band leader". I assume the star above is the reserved for band leader.

---

That's as much as I can get without more details. I recommend you make a request to the [US National Archives](https://www.archives.gov/veterans), you should be able to get details about your great grandfather.

Comment: Thanks very much for all of your help. I have discovered that he had another family in the US which means I now have more cousins. I'll try through army records to see what info they have on him, assuming he didn't change his name.